# Effect of water on an image

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

[image]

I am stuck on this question:

"consider the image above, P is an opaque disc (lying in a glass beaker) illuminated from bellow by a source S. A converging lens L forms an image of this at Q. Explain qualitatively how the position and size of the image of the disc is changed when the beaker is filled with water."

Here is my explanation (but I do not think it is right):

The image Q will be unaffected by the water in the beaker (i.e. it will be the same size and position as the image when there is no water). This is because the rays (assuming S is large enough) that reach L from the disc P will be parallel to the normal of the water's surface when both entering and leaving it and thus no refraction of the rays occurs. This means that the rays reaching L are exactly the same as when no water was in the beaker.

If this explanation is wrong please can you give me a HINT to the write answer rather then just the answer itself, thanks.

Comment: Forget the distance to the source;  you could be using a nearby streetlight, moonlight, or sunlight.  How are the rays from P affected by going through the water-air interface?

Comment: If they [the rays] are parallel to the water-air interface they will remain unaffected (expect a change in speed which should have no effect). But if not parallel then they would refract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate where an image is formed, you don't draw two parallel lines from the object to the lens (unless your object is at infinity).
To see where a point on the object would for a point after the lens (hence forming an image) draw a line that goes parallel to the optical axis (and is refracted to go through the focus on the other side), and another that passes through the focus of the lens (and is refracted to go parallel to the optical axis on the other side). where these two lines meet is where you'd get the image.
Now, you've got one light ray which is not parallel to the water's normal...